# close program in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, easygui

How can I close a program while i use multiprocessing from an existing process?

```
import easygui
import multiprocessing

def func():
    reply=easygui.buttonbox("start?",image="F:\project\phonber.png",choices=['yes','no'])
    if reply=="yes":
        exit_option()


if __name__=='__main__':
    p=multiprocessing.Process(target=func,args=())
    t=p.start()
    print "1"
    while True:
        None
```

I want that the `exit_option()` will shutdown the program.

Answer (score 0):

In sys module there is a function called [exit](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

Comment: i tried sys.exit() but it didnt work